# IDE Remix "Error encoding arguments: Error: expected array value"

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I have the following Solidity contract in IDE Remix:

pragma solidity 0.8.0;

```
//A contract with a customizable fee
contract EtherSplitter {
    function splitEther(address payable[] memory recipients, uint fee) public payable {
        
        recipients[0].transfer(msg.value * fee / 100);
        recipients[1].transfer(msg.value * (100 - fee) / 100);
    }
        receive() external payable {
    }
}
```

with the following settings to run:

- recipients: [0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C,
  0x4B0897b0513fdC7C541B6d9D7E929C4e5364D2dB]
- fee: 10
- value: 10 Ether.

When I press "Transact", I get the following error:

```
transact to EtherSplitter.splitEther errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: expected array value (argument=null, value="[0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C, 0x4B0897b0513fdC7C541B6d9D7E929C4e5364D2dB]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)
```

It seems there is an issue with how I am trying to specify fee. What is the error?

Answer (score 2):

Remix IDE accepts address type as a string, so you need to wrap the elements in quotes:

```
["0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C", "0x4B0897b0513fdC7C541B6d9D7E929C4e5364D2dB"]
```